# wix - Copy an entire directory and all of its contents

Tags: wix, wix3.5, heat

My wix installer needs the contents of a directory to be copied to a destination folder. I understand that the Directory element has a FileSource attrib. I tried something like this:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="DIRECTORY" FileSource="{var.Dir}">
  <Component Id="Dir" Guid="*" >
    <CreateFolder/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

This is not picking up the files or sub-directories from the preprocessor variable.

Are there any alternate ways to achieve this?

Comment: I'm looking to automate HEAT into my build process. Could anyone point me to any relevant helpful resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not unless you use a custom action.  WiX likes for every file to be tracked individually.  You can use `heat` to generate the directory listing for you.

Comment: I did read about integrating HEAT into the pre-build event. I was wondering if completely automating would imply adding the HEAT generated file into the solution.

Comment: Automatically generating every build means you're probably doing something wrong as far as MSI is concerned.  The whole point is to track each file with repeatable and consistent identifiers, which you may lose by autogeneration.

Answer (score 3):

Use heat.exe or HeatTask in MSBuild. That's the only way to do things today.

Comment: I need to copy directories from my project folder to installation folder.Need help to do this using wix please refer this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020130/how-to-copy-folder-files1-to-files5-during-the-installation-of-wix-installer and guide me