# MVC web application WIX installer

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, wix, wix3.6

I'm trying to create an installer using WIX for my MVC web application. I've followed this: http://blog.torresdal.net/2008/09/26/ blog article and I got it working. The issue is that in my `Product.wxs` I need to list all files I want to install ie:

```
<File Id="Web.config" Name="Web.config" ...
<File Id="MvcApplication4.dll" Name="MvcApplication4.dll" ...
```

etc..

During setup, wix install those files in ProgramFiles\MyApp\ directory. Which is good.

What I want to do instead is to have all files needed (like I would normally do using => publish) installed. meaning: bin, Views, Scripts etc.. and NOT have them listed one by one in Product.wxs.

OR

> Is there a way to specify in wix to copy a FOLDER and all contents
>   inside it?

any info would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Do you need to have an installer for a web application? I have had good success using https://github.com/manojlds/YDeliver. This is built over psake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wix - Copy an entire directory and all of its contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816289/wix-copy-an-entire-directory-and-all-of-its-contents).

Comment: Found answer: [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816289/wix-copy-an-entire-directory-and-all-of-its-contents

Using heat or Parafin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use Heat (http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm).

Heat will harvest files from your output directory if that is what you want.

More likely you will point it at a Visual Studio project and it will select all outputs and Copy to Output type files.

It is very flexible and is make to do exactly what you require, simply add it as a post build step.